# AJAX won't render my cart in my rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I am following the book 'Agile Development with Rails' by Sam Ruby, and consequently, I have been working on the depot application. Everything was fine till it came to AJAX based cart. I did everything what the book told to do, and yet, the cart won't render the newly added items unless I reload the whole page, which pretty much defeats the purpose of AJAX. My Rails version is 6.0.3.4, and my ruby version is 2.7.2.
This is the code in my line_items controller's create method:

```
def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        session[:counter] = 0
        format.html { redirect_to store_index_url }
        format.js
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the code in my create.js.coffee file in the app/views/line_items directory:

```
cart = document.getElementById("cart")
cart.innerHTML = "<%= j render(@cart) %>"
```

And this is the code in my index.html.erb file in the app/views/store directory:

```
<% if notice %>
  <aside id="notice"><%= notice %></aside>
<% end %>
<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>
<p>
    You've been here <%= @count %> times
</p>
<ul class="catalog">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <li>
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h2><%= product.title %></h2>
        <p>
          <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
        </p>
        <div class="price">
          <%= number_to_currency(product.price) %>
          <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true %>
        </div>
      </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It would be really helpful if someone could point out where I'm going wrong.
P.S - I don't know why, but when I only implement the remote: true part in the "Add to Cart" button in the index.html.erb file, (and not typing out 'format.js' in the line_items controller and not including the coffee file) it worked exactly like what the book mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, the problem is that coffeescript is deprecated after rails 5, and my project uses rails 6, and thus, the solution was to just change the extension of the file to .js.erb instead of .js.coffee .